# getting path of file in a folder in App bundle

Tags: ios, swift, bundle

My bundle has this structure: AppName->DevelopmentAssets->Images.

I would like to use UIImage(contentsOfFile:) method to initialize an image in Images file. I used this but is doesn't work. I suspect I must navigate to Images folder. How do I do that?

```
let stringPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("image3", ofType: "jpg")
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: stringPath!)!
```

image3 is inside Images folder.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("image3", ofType: "jpg", inDirectory: "Images")
```

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. You are very generous today:D. It complains that it found nil. hmm